# Using hardware encoders with third party apps?

Tags: video-editing, h.264

I have the [Avermedia Live Gamer HD (C985)](http://www.avermedia.com/Product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=571) PCIe Hardware Encoder that I used for video gameplay stream.

If I used the new XSplit 1.1, in CODEC settings, I can choose *Avermedia Encoder*. If I use the official app RECentral it takes advantage of the hardware encoder too, resulting in much faster encoder and almost no CPU usage.

Is there any way to take advantage of this with other applications, such as video converters, Adobe Premiere, Adobe After Effects, or apps that do transcoding?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since there is no API standard for hardware media encoders, each encoding library will need its own way to access the encoder.